# Differentiate a geometric sum and show that it is less than an equation

Tags: summation, induction

The question:

- a) Differentiate both sides of the geometric series with respect to $r$: $$~~\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^nr^i=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
- b) Use the result in part (a) to show that (Assume that $0 < r < 1$). $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$ for all $n\ge1$.

My attempts:

- a) $$\sum_{i=0}^nir^{i-1}=\frac{-(n+1)r^n(1-r)+(1-r^{n+1})}{(1-r)^2}$$
- b) With mathematical induction:
  $$P(n): \sum_{i=1}^nir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$

$$n=1, LHS = r, RHS = \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$ $$LHS < RHS$$

Assume $P(k)$ is true $$P(k): \sum_{i=1}^kir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$

Prove $P(k+1)$ is true: $$P(k+1): \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}ir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^kir^i+\sum_{i=k+1}^{k+1}ir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$

I am currently stuck here.

Comment: You will get better response if you post your question here and not a link to your question.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: First, part b) requires some restriction on $r$. Second, you should include what you have done to solve a) and attack b).

Comment: Shouldn't the RHS of the inequality involve some $n$? The sum on the LHS diverges, so clearly it is not smaller than the number of the RHS for any $n$.

Comment: @Lovsovs No the sum on the LHS does not always diverge, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Did Yes, you are of course right, thanks for the correction! Oh, and OP included the necessary restriction, great!

Comment: @Frentos thanks for editing the question ealier :) I have included my attempts as well